# How to access test/example/fragment name in Specs2 before and after methods?

Tags: scala, specs2

I would like to do something like:

```
class MySpec extends Specification with BeforeAfterExample {
  var testName
  var clientDir

  def before {
    testName = fragmentName.replaceAll(" ", "-")
    clientDir = new File(workspaceRoot, testName)
    clientDir.mkdirs()
  }

  def after {
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(clientDir)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would probably work:

```
class MySpec extends Specification with BeforeAfterExample {
  var currentExample = 0
  var testName = ""
  var clientDir:File = null

  def before {
    testName = is.examples(currentExample).desc.toString.replaceAll(" ", "-")
    clientDir = new File(workspaceRoot, testName)
    clientDir.mkdirs()
  }

  def after {
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(clientDir)
    currentExample += 1    
  }
}
```

I don't think you can get much context in the before and after methods without doing something kind of hacky like this.

Comment: Since a copy of the Spec is made for each example, this doesn't work. OTOH, your answer helps in that it gives me more context as to how specs2 works. I can just create and destroy the directories inside beforeSpec and afterSpec.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want by using specs2 `ExampleFactory`

```
import org.specs2._
import specification._

class TestSpec extends Specification { def is =
  "test" ! {
    ok
  }
  case class BeforeAfterExample(e: Example) extends BeforeAfter {
    def before = println("before "+e.desc)
    def after  = println("after "+e.desc)
  }
  override def exampleFactory = new ExampleFactory {
    def newExample(e: Example) = {
      val context = BeforeAfterExample(e)
      e.copy(body = () => context(e.body()))
    }
  }
}
```

This part of the API has only been opened recently so it's only available in 1.15-SNAPSHOT for now (You can work around this restriction with a less recent specs2 version by creating your factory directly in a package starting with `org.specs2`).

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky, but this works for me:

```
/**
 * Returns the name of the currently executing example
 */
def getCurrentExampleName(spec: Specification): String = {

  val stack = new Exception().getStackTrace
  val specLinesUpStack = for (
    line <- stack
      if line.getClassName.startsWith(spec.getClass.getName))
        yield line.getLineNumber

  spec.is.examples
    .find(e => specLinesUpStack.contains(e.location.lineNumber))
    .get
    .desc.toString()
}
```